# Python client-server communication over SSL

Tags: python, ssl, python-3.4

I am using Python 3.4.2. I am writing a simple program for client-server communication using SSL. But when I run this program in Python, it gets stuck at `import ssl`. I did check the documentation and we have an SSL module. Can anyone please explain where the problem is? Below is my code.

Server Code:

```
import socket
import ssl

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)  

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5600
print(host,port)

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    conn = context.wrap_socket(c, server_side = True)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    x = "thank you for connecting to server"
    conn.send(x.encode())  
    conn.close()
```

Client Code:

```
import socket
import ssl

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5600
print(host,port)
s = socket.socket()
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)

conn = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname = host)
conn.connect((host, port))

data = conn.recv(1024)
print(data)
```

Comment: Are there any error messages or other helpful output?

Comment: For me it passes the `import` just fine but then both sides die on the `do_handshake` implied by `wrap_socket` (server-side; by `connect`, client-side) because "no shared cipher" (server side) and thus "handshake failure (client side), just as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478048/no-shared-cipher-error-with-python-and-openssl that I recommend you check.  However "gets stuck at `import ssl`" is a different issue -- maybe you happen to have an `ssl.py` around in the `PYTHONPATH` before the real one?

Comment: `no shared cipher` is probably because your server does not have any certificates configured and thus can only do ciphers without authentication (like ADH). But the client usually will not offer such ciphers for security reasons.

Comment: I intaled it agian and it worked & now i am facing some another problem                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PRATIK\Desktop\Test Client.py", line 12, in <module>
    conn.connect((host, port))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 841, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 832, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 805, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:600)

Comment: @ Alex Martelli -  any solution as to how to overcome this handshake error